# Call parent in constructor c#

Tags: c#

I want to do something like this:

```
Parent parent = new Parent(new Child(parent));
```

VS tells me parent is unknown variable.

I don't want such initialization:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child=new Child(parent);
parent.Child=child;
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to do something like this"? What is that supposed to achieve?

Comment: It's essentially for traversing, linked list style.

Comment: Which came first, the chicken or the egg? You have written this statement in C#.

Comment: You are true, this is probably more an inheritance problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better solution might be to have a constructor in `Parent` that creates the child for you:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child {get; set;}

    public Parent()
    {
        Child = new Child(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you think about it, you're trying to pass to child your parent while you're actually trying to create parent in the first place.  When you do `new Child()`, parent doesn't exist yet, so there is nothing to pass in.

What you can do however is this:

```
class Parent
{
    public Child CreateChild()
    {
         return new Child(this)
    }
}
```

and thus:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child= parent.CreateChild();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thy this

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(Child ch)
    {
        this.Child = ch;
        this.Child.Parent = this;
    }

    public Child Child {get; set;}
}
```

Initialization:

```
Parent parent = new Parent(new Child());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is impossible. Best guess for what you want, without more informations, is to have the parent constructor instantiate the child, sending it 'this'.

```
class Parent
{
  public Parent()
  {
     _child = new Child(this);
  }
   private Child _child;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the syntax were possible, `parent` wouldn't have a useful value until after the call (it's probably `null`).  You would need to set a new value, anyway.

The closest equivalent to that process I can think of would be for the `Parent` class to create the `Child` inside its constructor, passing itself to the `Child` constructor.  Then it can set its own `.child` member to that resulting object and you have the structure you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public class Parent
{
    private IList<Child> _children = new List<Child>();

    public Parent() {} // probably don't want to hide default ctor

    public Parent(Child c)
    {
        AddChild(c);
    }

    public Parent AddChild(Child c)
    {
        c.Parent = this;
        _children.Add(c);
        return this;
    }

    public IList<Child> Children { get { return _children; } }
}

public class Child
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
Parent parent = new Parent()
    .AddChild(new Child())
    .AddChild(new Child());
```

Or

```
Parent parent = new Parent(new Child())
    .AddChild(new Child());
```

You have flexibility